# The correct answer format when looking for the difference between two dates

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm having a problem, I have a code that I'm looking for the time difference

```html
select (to_date(:P26_DATA_UNPLUG , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:ss')
    -  to_date(:P26_DATA_PLUG, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:ss')) * 24
from dual;
```

I will answer this query similar to "2.34636..." but I want them to be of this format:'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:ss'. Is there anything that can be done ??
And one more question, when I get the answer "2.34636", the number of these numbers is too many, but can one somehow make my answer match 5 characters ??

Comment: There is no built-in way to represent that number in the format "dd.mm.yyyy hh24:ss", you would have to calculate it yourself and construct the string - how many years, how many remaining months etc. etc.  For the number of decimal places you can use the TRUNC, ROUND, FLOOR or CEIL functions - see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html#GUID-849F6C45-0D72-4464-9C0F-8B6822BA85E1

Comment: You may also need to consider INTERVAL data types, for whatever it is you need https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DSINTERVAL.html#GUID-DEBB41BD-9438-4558-A53E-428CE93C05D3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally doesn't make sense to try to represent the difference between two dates in a date format.  If you have two dates that are a couple of days apart, does it really make sense to return a value that represents "January 3, 0001 at 8:15:00 am" (roughly 2.34 days after January 1, 001 at midnight)?  And things get harder when the differences get larger because converting days to months and years gets very, very non-obvious.  If you have two dates that are exactly 1 month apart but that month is 30 days long, do you return "January 31, 0001", 30 days after Jan 1, or "February 1, 0001", 1 month after Jan 1.

If you convert the two fields to timestamps rather than days and subtract them, you'll get an interval which is a much more appropriate way to represent the difference between two points in time.  You can then do things like extract the various components of the interval or convert the interval to a string.

```
with x as (
select to_timestamp( '19.09.2019 11:26:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) -
         to_timestamp( '01.01.2019 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) diff
  from dual
)
select to_char( diff ),
       extract( day from diff ) days,
       extract( hour from diff ) hours,
       extract( minute from diff ) minutes,
       extract( second from diff ) seconds
  from x;
```

Note that you can't use `extract` to get months or years because there isn't an unambiguous way to represent that.  If you want to implement your own logic to figure out what "years" and "months" means to you, you're free to do so by manipulating the days (i.e. in finance, you often work off 360 day years with 12 30 day months so it's easy enough to divide by 30 without caring whether you're dealing with a 28 or a 31 day month in reality).

Comment: thanks for the help, this is what i wanted, but the answer is in 4 columns, and can it be done somehow in one column? i'm doing this in the command "UPDATE SEC_SEALING_STATUS set data = (with x as (
select to_timestamp ('19 .09.2019 11:26:00 ',' dd.mm.yyyy hh24: mi: ss') -
          to_timestamp ('01 .01.2019 00:00:00 ',' dd.mm.yyyy hh24: mi: ss') diff
   from dual
)
select to_char (diff),
        extract (day from diff) days,
        extract (hour from diff) hours,
        extract (minutes from diff) minutes,
        extract (second from diff) seconds
   from x;) "

Comment: And maybe you know how to crop the answer to my query ??? I get "+000000000 00: 00: 08.000000000" I want to have "000 00:00:08"